# What's the follow-up scenario to Pathfinder Society Scenario #1-07: Flooded King's Court?

Tags: published-adventures, pathfinder-2e, product-identification, pathfinder-society

I'm running Pathfinder Society scenarios I picked up on sale for my group. They've expressed interest in the storyline that begins in Pathfinder Society Scenario #1-07: Flooded King's Court, but I can't tell which scenario or quest finishes the story began in it, specifically

> when one of the two boons Blast from the Past or To Seal and Protect are used.

The scenario specifies that a follow-up would be published after it, and both its season and the following season have been published. What is the name of the follow-up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No - or not yet?

There isn't another adventure which either references those boons or the events of *The Flooded King's Court*.

This is based on:

- My own experiences with PFS, having GM'd about half of the extant adventures.
- Conversations with other local PFS players/GMs
- Asking the [same question](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs43etg?Where-do-the-boons-from-Flooded-Kings-Court#1) on the PFS forums and receiving a single response which also said "no".
- Googling "Marcon Tinol" to see if they appear in any other adventures.

### What to look out for?

Starting in the second season, Paizo phased out the boons on chronicle sheets for ones that can be purchased in their online portal. The descriptions may provide you some additional details to help identify when a relavent one comes available:

> Blast from the Past: A surviving NPC will remember your actions.

> To Seal and Protect: A destroyed NPC will have consequences.

Comment: I did the internet research but don't play PFS, and hadn't played the scenarios in question. Glad that I'm not just bad at searching

Answer (score 1):

According to Pathfinder wiki there is no follow-up yet.
Usually information on Pathfinder society can be found on the below links where under metaplot/notes column often you can find specific informations like direct sequels and so on.

[Year of the open road](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Year_of_the_Open_Road)

[Year of corruption's reach](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Year_of_Corruption%27s_Reach)

EDIT: That wiki is pretty solid and updated but keep in mind that is always a fan made wiki.

Comment: Erm... both those pages say that their ongoing plot sections are stubs.

Comment: If you read the tables entry there is always written when a scenario is a sequel to another scenario and there is no sequel for #1-07 FKC.

Comment: It's a wiki, so I'm not sure "always" is the best word for it, although it's good to point out that users *try* to make note of sequels. I would definitely put that in the answer, since otherwise this is little more than a link-only answer

Comment: @Ifusaso Added a note to point out that is a wiki. Unfortunately the informations the user is searching are really niche and there is really not much to find.

Comment: I actually meant that the metaplot/notes column usually identifies direct sequels